# Multiple IFs for different conditional selections inside a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I have an issue when I try to calculate the number of rows inside my table, using a multiple separated ifs condition inside a trigger to test the field if it's different from empty.

I have tried to put the if out from select function and it work but I can't do it for all the cases that I have, it will be not optimized.

```
BEGIN
UPDATE max_tare
SET max_row = (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM history 
IF(NEW.client != '') THEN
WHERE nom LIKE CONCAT('%', NEW.client, '%') END IF;
    
IF(NEW.commune != '') THEN
WHERE commune LIKE CONCAT('%', NEW.commune, '%') END IF;
    
IF(NEW.type != '') THEN
WHERE type LIKE CONCAT('%', NEW.type, '%') END IF;
    
IF(NEW.matricule != '') THEN
WHERE mat LIKE CONCAT('%', NEW.matricule, '%') END IF;

IF(NEW.tare != '') THEN
WHERE tare LIKE CONCAT('%', NEW.tare, '%') END IF;

WHERE cancled = 0), 
    max_tare =
    (SELECT SUM(tare)
     FROM history
     WHERE cancled = 0) WHERE id = 1;

END
```

in php query I got the row number easy, but when I tried the trigger I got an error saying:

> MySQL replied: # 1064 - Syntax error near '`IF`' (new.client! = '') THEN
> WHERE name LIKE CONCAT ('%', NEW.client, '%') `END IF`;

I will lend the php code used under codeigniter framework this works perfectly,

```
$this->db->select("*");
            
$this->db->from('history');

if ($query[1] != '') {
    $this->db->like('nom', $query[1]);
                }
if ($query[2] != '') {
    $this->db->like('commune', $query[2]);
                }
if ($query[3] != '') {
    $this->db->like('type', $query[3]);
                }
if ($query[4] != '') {
    $this->db->like('mat', $query[4]);
                }
if ($query[10] != '') {
    $this->db->like('rfid', $query[10]);
                }
if ($query[5] != '') {
    $this->db->like('tare', $query[5]);
                }
if ($query[6] != '') {
    $this->db->where('date >', $query[6]);
                }
if ($query[7] != '') {
    $this->db->where('date <', $query[7]);
                }
if ($query[11] != '') {
    $this->db->where('time_plode >', $query[11]);
                }
if ($query[12] != '') {
    $this->db->where('time_plode <', $query[12]);
                }
$this->db->where('cancled', 0);
return $this->db->count_all_results();
```

this code will return the count number of rows and it works fine under php, but I want to use it in trigger rather than php query.

hope with this I am more clear

I will try to make an example:

```
+----+--------+---------+------+--------------+------+
|                     temp_fetch                     |
+----+--------+---------+------+--------------+------+
| id | client | commune | type | matricule    | tare |
+----+--------+---------+------+--------------+------+
| 1  | EPIC   |         |      |              |      |
+----+--------+---------+------+--------------+------+
```

this is my triggered table that will activate when I update it, let's just assume it's have been updated to this case here
and now I will try to filter my result to count them

```
+----+-------------+---------+--------+--------------+-------+---------+---------+
|                                      history                                   |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+--------------+-------+---------+---------+
| id | nom         | commune | type   | mat          | tare  | rfid    | cancled |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+--------------+-------+---------+---------+
| 1  | EPIC paris  | france  | white  | 01248-816-16 | 7600  | ABCF44C | 0       |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+--------------+-------+---------+---------+
| 2  | EPIC london | UK      | white  | 06854-315-16 | 5233  | A8CG27C | 1       |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+--------------+-------+---------+---------+
| 3  | NET barça   | ESP     | red    | 03254-615-16 | 8900  | HBC54AC | 1       |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+--------------+-------+---------+---------+
| 4  | NET Dubai   | arab    | blue   | 35251-117-16 | 11200 | HDK7BV5 | 0       |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+--------------+-------+---------+---------+
| 5  | EPIC roma   | ita     | red    | 36524-618-16 | 7300  | NBL53DC | 0       |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+--------------+-------+---------+---------+
| 6  | SNC beta    | alpha   | green  | 69358-117-16 | 5400  | JDLF8ND | 1       |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+--------------+-------+---------+---------+
| 7  | EPIC tokyo  | japan   | yellow | 46258-712-16 | 8700  | K5ND55D | 1       |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+--------------+-------+---------+---------+
| 8  | SARL Fit    | body    | black  | 69531-614-16 | 9600  | AIES5HJ | 0       |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+--------------+-------+---------+---------+
```

So this is my table that I want to count rows inside that match with my array table (1st one)
So my desired result inside my table max_tare :

```
+----------------------------+
|          max_tare          |
+----------------------------+
| id |  max_row   | max_tare |
+----+------------+----------+
| 1  |     2      | 14900    |
+----+------------+----------+
```

that counted two row rows they have `nom like epic` and `where cancled = 0`
hopefully now its clear as I added simple data

when I try `Danblack` solution which is

```
UPDATE max_tare
SET max_row =
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM history
   WHERE nom LIKE CONCAT('%', NEW.client, '%')
     AND commune LIKE CONCAT('%', NEW.commune, '%')
     AND TYPE LIKE CONCAT('%', NEW.type, '%')
     AND mat LIKE CONCAT('%', NEW.matricule, '%')
     AND tare LIKE CONCAT('%', NEW.tare, '%')
     AND cancled = 0),
    max_tare =
  (SELECT SUM(tare)
   FROM history
   WHERE cancled = 0)
WHERE id = 1;
```

I don't get :

```
+----------------------------+
|          max_tare          |
+----------------------------+
| id |  max_row   | max_tare |
+----+------------+----------+
| 1  |     0      | 14900    |
+----+------------+----------+
```

and this is not what I want, the problem with this solution is that it search in my table any data that can be empty.

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: `!=` should be together, without space (in the case if you have pasted this error message correctly)

Comment: Incorrect syntax in so many places. Please read the documentation.

Comment: @MichaelO. they are together wwithout spaces, ad i said i used this syntax in differents other codes and it worked fine but in this case it wont i don't know why :'(

Comment: @Hermanto where do you see the spaces that cause the problem.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would all help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff now i have added what  you did suggested hopefully it will help me to get an answer to my problem :) ty for teh suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the there is an `IF` function and an `IF` statement. They look different and are relevant in different parts of SQL syntax.

Could this be simpler by not considering the empty string in an if statement and just using:

```
UPDATE max_tare
SET max_row =
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM history
   WHERE nom LIKE CONCAT('%', NEW.client, '%')
     AND commune LIKE CONCAT('%', NEW.commune, '%')
     AND TYPE LIKE CONCAT('%', NEW.type, '%')
     AND mat LIKE CONCAT('%', NEW.matricule, '%')
     AND tare LIKE CONCAT('%', NEW.tare, '%')
     AND cancled = 0),
    max_tare =
  (SELECT SUM(tare)
   FROM history
   WHERE cancled = 0)
WHERE id = 1;
```

After all '%%' as a pattern matches all.

Comment: `AND WHERE cancled = 0` should be `AND cancled = 0`

Comment: @danblack thanks for the quick answer, but i have already tried this, when i try to count without considerating the empty fields, it will send  0 row  as result because none  of them contains empty string :'(.

Comment: Your made up syntax and lack for clear explanation leaves little clue as to what you want the result to be. I guess. Was wrong. Please edit the question with some sample data and expected results

Comment: @danblack what i want really, is to use  a field only if its different then empty, 
for exemple :  
if NEW.commune is empty, it will not be executed and it will passe the the next one.
can  i put my php code in codeigniter maybe  this will help to be more clear.

Comment: @phpbegginernoob . . . This code seems really reasonable and is probably what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have edited and added my php code so you can figure what i want exactly, because what danblack mentioned is good, but it dont fit my requirements, i want to check like  only if its not empty 
thanks in advance for the help and sorry for my bad english i am trying to improve

Comment: @danblack is it okai now that i described more the problem, and the solution that i got here isn't really adapted to the question, because  my title  is multiple nested if inside a trigger for mutiple selecting cases

Comment: btw haven't responded because a) the sample data still looks like the answer should be the solution assuming `temp_fetch` is inserted. A [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0) to prove your results would help (and it could be something simple like the difference between NULL, empty string and spaces b) you're insisting on an answer in a particular from even though the SQL language doesn't support it. c) [duplicating the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56290552/nested-ifs-in-a-select-where-for-a-conditional-dynamic-filtering) won't give you a different answer.